# SetExpressCheckout not working in Netbeans

Tags: paypal

I have installed paypal merchant sdk on my remote server using install.php.
Now I have connected to my remote server using netbeans and downloaded all the codes.

I am getting the following error on my browser when I am executing my setExpressCheckout funtion.

**include(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

```
**This is my code in Controller :**

    public function actionexpress(){



$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService($config_checkout);
$paymentDetails= new PaymentDetailsType();

$orderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
$orderTotal->currencyID = 'USD';
$orderTotal->value = 500;

$paymentDetails->OrderTotal = $orderTotal;
$paymentDetails->PaymentAction = 'Sale';

$setECReqDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
$setECReqDetails->PaymentDetails[0] = $paymentDetails;
$setECReqDetails->CancelURL = 'https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec/php?cancel=true';
$setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = 'xyz.com';

$billingAgreementDetails = new BillingAgreementDetailsType('RecurringPayments');
$billingAgreementDetails->BillingAgreementDescription = 'Hello';
$setECReqDetails->BillingAgreementDetails = array($billingAgreementDetails);

$setECReqType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
//$setECReqType->Version = '3.0';
$setECReqType->Version = '104.0';
$setECReqType->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $setECReqDetails;

$setECReq = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
$setECReq->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $setECReqType;

$setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);
die(var_dump($setECResponse));





}
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having problem with setting path for the php files of merchant sdk which I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have resolved my problem.

The only problem is with paths , I have explicitly given all the paths and worked, and finally after 4 hours I am able to get the output.